# Saving in txt format in Matlab with commas and semicolons

Tags: matlab

I have a huge matrix in Matlab that I want to save in .txt format (or in any other text format).

Suppose the matrix is

```
A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

If I type `save prova.txt A -ASCII` I get the matrix in .txt format as

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

(in an horrible exponential form, actually)

I would like to get instead

1, 2, 3;

4, 5, 6;

7, 8, 9;

Can you help me? In addition, do you know a way to make the exponential form disappear?

Comment: If you can make do with the result in string form, you can use `str = num2str(A, '%i, '); str(:,end) = ';';` (or change the format specifier to `'%f'` or whatever you need)
`

Comment: I can follow you till str = num2str(A, '%i, '); str(:,end) = ';'; which creates a char variable. Then, how can I save it in text format?

Comment: Use `fopen`, `fprintf` and `fclose`.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What should I write exactly?

Comment: @user3285148 - I'll write an answer.  Hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the approach by Luis Mendo to convert your numeric array to a character matrix that is comma delimited with a semi-colon at the end of each row:

```
str = num2str(A, '%i, '); 
str(:,end) = ';';
```

Next, convert each of the rows of the character array into a cell array:

```
s = mat2cell(str, ones(1,size(str,1)), size(str,2));
```

Now, use `fopen`, `fprintf` and `fclose` to write the data to file:

```
fid = fopen('prova.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', s{:});
fclose(fid);
```

This is what I get when I examine `prova.txt`:

```
1, 2, 3;
4, 5, 6;
7, 8, 9;
```

Comment: I want also semicolons

Comment: @user3285148 - I changed my answer.